# Inputting a list of numbers into a function?

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with a list of numbers all in one column for my input values, and want to use a defined function to spit out a list of output numbers. The function works fine as I tested with floating numbers, but I'm getting an error when inputting the list. What I have so far is:

```
#Read in text file 
text_file = open('example.txt', "r")

#Converting file into list
ex_list = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()

#Defining function 
def f(x):
return (x - (5*math.log10(132)))

#Now inputting list of numbers into function 
f(ex_list)
```

But I'm getting an error saying "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'" which I'm assuming doesn't like the list format. I checked, and each value is a string of size 8, when I'm guessing should be an integer of size 1. So I didn't convert the list properly, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code would not raise that error. In any case, what do you *expect* `x = (5*math.log10(132))` to *do* when `x` is a list?

Comment: I thought it would spit out another list as my output, so how could I do that with my function?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure that if someone else copies and pastes your code, and provides the exact input you specify (better yet, hard-code the input in some way), that it will produce the exact error message you describe (which you should also copy and paste, formatted as code, [in its entirety](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)).

Comment: @AmmarBayyari why did you think that??? Did you see what happens if you do `[1, 2, 3] - 10`, for example?

Comment: Because I am very new to coding, so I'd appreciate any help for my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what level of experience you have. You need to ask a *clear* question before it is possible for anyone to help you. Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `example.txt` file looks like this

```
0.772572
0.228697
9.053680
0.301091
0.051380
```

Then the following code will read in each line and convert the line to a number. The output will be a list of floats.

```
#Read in text file 
text_file = open('example.txt', "r")

#Converting file into list
ex_list = [float(line.strip()) for line in text_file]
text_file.close()
```

Your function will not work on a list of numbers, though. But you can map the function to the list. The result will be a list of the result of applying `f()` to each number in the file.

```
output = list(map(f, ex_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
import math

with open('example.txt') as fo:
    content = [int(i.strip()) for i in fo.readlines()]

def f(x):
    return (x - (5*math.log10(132)))


print([f(i) for i in content])
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` takes a `float` as an argument, not a `list`. So, instead of what you did, proceed like this:

**First solution**: Your function takes a `list` as an argument:

```
def f(L):
for i in L:
    print(float(i) - (5*math.log10(132))) #use print, not return!
```

**Second solution**: you call `f` on each element of your list

```
def f(x):
    return (x - (5*math.log10(132)))

fro i in ex_list:
    print(f(float(i)))
```

I hope that this will help